# HostListener OnClick Only Works Sometimes

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am experiencing some uneven results while trying to create a drop-down box in Angular (I was following [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883020/how-to-perform-window-onclick-on-angular-v4)). Here is my code:

html

````
           ``` <button (click)="eqLocationDrop()" id="eqLocButton"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i> </button>
         <div id="eqLocDD" class="dropdown-content" *ngIf="showEQDD">
            <option *ngFor="let e of eqLoc" class="option" (click)="ddClick(e)">{{e.Loc}}
            </option>
          </div>```
````

ts

```
   if (event.target == document.getElementById("eqLocButton")) {

     console.log("button clicked");
   } else { //hide the drop down box, as a click has occurred outside the box
     this.showEQDD = false;
    console.log("button did NOT get clicked");
    }
   } 

 eqLocationDrop() { //show the drop down div
   this.showEQDD = true;
   }

 ddClick(e) {     // on click of an item in the drop down menu - get the data and hide the drop down
   console.log(e)
   this.showEQDD = false;

 }
```

Testing this out, I get the "button NOT clicked" when I click anywhere outside the drop down button; however, when the drop down button is clicked, it will seemingly randomly work as intended and then immediately stop working with no discernible pattern. When it does function properly, it can never be closed and then immediately reopened. Am I not doing the if() for the check if the button was clicked correctly? It seems as if event.target is changing at random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple - I tried console logging the event.target object, and I learned that I was sometimes clicking the button, and sometimes the button's icon. I had thought that the icon was innately part of the button, but apparently it counts as its own object, and thus stops the drop-down menu from working. I was able to put some text into this button and did this:

```
html
<button id="eqButton" ><p id="v">V</p></button>

ts
    if(event.target == document.getElementById("eqButton") || event.target == document.getElementById("v")) {
    } else {
      this.showEDD = false;
    }
```